# PHP, require ../

Tags: php, require, lighttpd

Всем добрый вечер, я совсем новичек в php (изучаю пару часов). У меня возникли проблемы с require. Мое приложение находится в /var/www/html. Ошибка в следующем, есть файл MyBook.php, который лежит как:

```
/var/www/html/php/data/MyBook.php
```

и файл MyBaseUtils.php, лежит как:

```
/var/www/html/php/base/MyBaseUtils.php
```

Мне нужен доступ к описанию класса внутри MyBook.php из MyBaseUtils.php. Делаю:

```
require "../data/MyBook.php";
```

В браузере ошибка:

> Warning: require(../data/MyBook.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/base/MyBaseUtils.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../data/MyBook.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/php/base/MyBaseUtils.php on line 4

Может проблема не в самом PHP? Веб-сервер lighttpd, ОС: Debian 8, версия php: 5.6.14-0+deb8u1.

Comment: Попробуйте `require "/../data/MyBook.php";`. Либо `require __DIR__ . "/../data/MyBook.php";`

Comment: Не работает. 

Но работает например `require "/var/www/html/php/data/MyBook.php";`. Правда такой вариант не подходит.

Ошибку кстати выдает такую же:
`Warning: require(/../data/MyBook.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/base/MyBaseUtils.php on line 4`

Comment: Не сразу заметил что между `__DIR__` и `"` есть еще и точка. Теперь работает, спасибо большое!

Comment: @danil Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать вариант с использованием "волшебной" константы [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
require __DIR__ . "/../data/MyBook.php";
```